# How to update meteor bundle, without losing data?

Tags: meteor

After deployed the meteor app using bundle, can I update the app without losing data? How?

Comment: what do you mean? The data in a deployed bundle resides in a mongo db you provide (`MONGO_URL`). That db is not affected by redeployment.

Comment: @ChristianFritz So, I can just override the bundle with the new one? Wouldn't the mongodb be overrided as well?

Comment: no, because the bundle doesn't contain the db. from http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying: "To run this application, you need to provide Node.js 0.10 and a MongoDB server."

Comment: posted it as an answer with additional detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is not affected by redeploying. As described in "Running on your own infrastructure"  of the documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying), you need to provide your own mongodb for running a bundle, specified via the `MONGO_URL`, e.g.:

```
$ MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js
```

When you overwrite the bundle with a new one, this does not touch the database.

In my production environments I usually follow a workflow like this to update my app that is already running in a `screen`:

```
1. cd meteorapp/
2. git pull
3. meteor bundle ../bundle.tgz 
4. cd ..
5. tar xf bundle.tgz 
6. screen -r
7. (in screen): MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js
```

This works fine and no data has ever been lost in this process.